# Set values in summer note text editor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django, summernote

I want to set dynamic values in the summer note text editor using JavaScript/jQuery. I have tried to set value with both but nothing works for me.

```
document.getElementById('summernote').innerHTML = data.message;


$('.summernote').summernote('code', data.message);
```

Can anyone help me with how I can add values in summer note using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Can you try this: document.getElementById('summernote').innerText= data.message;

Comment: @tirth1620, It is not working,

Comment: $("#EDITsummernote").innerHtml = 'test';
You should try this way also

Comment: @CaptionAmerica, I have tried this also but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my Answer. I am fetching with summernote class not with ID.

```
$("#summernote").summernote('code', data.message);
```